# "Very much true": how often have you heard a native speaker say that?

Tags: word-usage

How often have you heard a native speaker say "very much true"?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzMx1Oo7hvg&t=0m18s

Comment: Redundant but unfortunately [very much in use](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22very+much+true%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb) by native speakers.

Comment: You mean, it's one of the common errors made by native speakers?

Comment: I wouldn't call it an error. But qualifiers such as "very," "quite", and "sort of" are just clutter, as Zinsser would say.

Comment: Not necessarily an error or clutter - it's a way of intensifying the quality: `true < very true < very much true`, similar to `noisy < quite noisy < really noisy < really quite noisy`.

Comment: Very much so is more common.

Comment: Runglish: no, "redundancy" does not mean "error". These are two completely different words that mean two completely different things. But it is not even necessarily redundant in the first place.

Comment: While I understand the phrase when she says it in the video, it strikes me as awkward -- it makes her sound like a non-native speaker. But her Indian accent may also be biasing me. _very true_ is fairly common, but I don't think _very much true_ is.

Comment: Related: the Spanish phrase "Claro que sí"

Answer (score 7):

Grammatically, it is perfectly valid to say something is "very much xxx", where xxx is an adjective.

Semantically, it is a superlative - intepretation depends on what the proposition is that the statement "it is very much true" is referring to.

Some propositions are either true or false - e.g. *today is Saturday* - there's not much room for this to be only "partly" true, so equally it wouldn't make sense to say it is "very much true".

There are, however, plenty of propositions which may legitimately be argued to be only partly true - e.g. *it is a cold day today* - the truth or falseness of this statement depend partly on the actual weather, and partly on the perceptions of those complaining about it.

An Alaskan might say *"false, it's not cold today"*, to which a Floridian might respond, *"what? no! it's very much true!"*

Comment: Do you seriously believe that, grammatically, is it really perfectly correct to say "very much tall" or "very much beautiful"? :-) Nevertheless, we have "very much the same".

Have you watched the video the link to which I posted above?

Comment: Yes, I watched it.